# How to output xmlns in children when generating sample xml from xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

When I create an XSD for each schema and then reference all of them in a "main" schema using imports, the xmlns entries are all at the  level, but I need them to show up in its corresponding child element.

Here is what the final xml would look like:

```
<message>
  <element1 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyOrg.MyNameSpace">
    <something>test</something>
    <somethingelse>
      <Address xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyOrg.Address">
         <a:AddressLine1>123 Main St</a:AddressLine1>
      </Address>
    </somethingelse>
  </element1>
</message>
```

Any idea how to do this in the xsd definition?

Comment: Why do you need that? Think about it: what is the issue that prevent you from using namespace prefixes where appropriate?

Comment: Are you using the XSD to generate an instance, perhaps? If so, using what tool? If not, I don't understand the question.

Comment: The client has instructed us to put the reference in there so their handler routes it correctly. I haven't tried to shoot an XML through without the xmlns and just the a: record. It definetley fails if I don't put either, it needs to get to a data contract in a different namespace.

Comment: Also I had a mistake up there, we do have "a:" in our XML. @Michael I am putting the XSD in the LiquidXML utility and generating a sample XML to see if it looks like the output I gave above.

Comment: It looks like I can put the xmlns at the root level and it works. I think in this situation the client may be using the wrong approach. Any other thoughts?

Comment: So it turns out the method I have above, while maybe not best practice, is consumed correctly by the deserializer. For some reason the program they use to generate the XML only supports 1 XSD per XML message and the xmlns are not put at the root, rather at the respective child element. They are using CorePoint.